# Which version of Android Studio should I use on an old laptop?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have 7-years-old Dell Inspiron M5040 laptop. I tried to install&use latest versions of Android Studio, but I saw that it lags too much. What version of Android Studio can you recommend me based on the parameters of my laptop?
Laptop specs: AMD Dual Core E450 1.65GHz, RAM 6GB, HDD 320GB, 1366x768, AMD Radeon HD 6320, Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: No version of Android Studio will run particularly well on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say but the configuration you've provided is not suitable for Android app development in Android Studio. You should buy a new configuration Laptop/PC having at least Core i5 2 gHz clock speed and 8 GB of ram. Then you can run Android Studio smoothly. Otherwise it will lag and you will get demotivated in every step of your android development. You can check details here. https://developer.android.com/studio/

Comment: Thank you, I know about that, but aren't old versions of Android Studio requesting less system requirements?

Comment: @ОлегМедведев The oldest version was (0.1 x) released in May 2013. I installed that in my core i5 1.6 Ghz, 4 GB ram ddr3 laptop. But it was still lagging significantly. I had to wait a considerable time just to open the Android Studio, let alone do anything in it. Later I changed my laptop to my given answer and working fine now. Now you decide.

Answer (score 1):

This setting is far from desirable but it should work. This lag may be due to excessive disk usage caused by windows defender. Try putting android studio on the exceptions and check for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio IDE is heavy. You have only 6GB RAM. You can try Android Studio under Linux or install Eclipse IDE. I don't think it's a good idea to install old version Android Studio.